# Making an edit seems to be a duplicate of another question

Tags: discussion

For an example, say I have posted a question with 3 issues.

Then I figured another particular issue and I made a separate post for that.

Someone gives me some solution. I work on the solution. It solves the current issue and it also partially solves my previous issues.

I leave a comment to the solution. The person asks me to update my question.

After updating the question(to clarify the whole scenario), it closely becomes a duplicate to the previously asked question of mine.

What shall I do then? If the previous question doesn't have any answer, I can delete the question. But if someone gave me an answer which is not solving my problem, then the question is not solved. Also, I can't delete my previous question since it contains an answer.

In such case, should I flag my previous question for moderator's attention stating that it's a duplicate of my current question?

Comment: A 3-for-1 deal? Seems "too broad".

Comment: Yes, actually the issues were small, but tricky. Moreover they were interlinked.

Answer (score -1):

Edit the second question just for the 'another particular issue' and edit your main question, add a link to the second one so that people would know that you have your problem partitially solved, but you still need their help ;)
I would do that :P